# create a java application to get information from another java application

Tags: java

I have a java application that generate informations and print out those informations on the screen.My problem is to get out this information and transfer them to another java application.this application has an its own main.I know that it seems too general but I don't know how explain this case study better

Comment: Is the source code of BOTH applications under your control?

Comment: Yes...it is totally under my control...

Answer (score 5):

Your question **is** to general, but here are few pointers (from most low-level to most comprehensive):

- [pipe](/questions/tagged/pipe) output in console:

  ```
  $ java -jar first-app.jar | java -jar second-app.jar
  ```

  In this scenario all console output from `first-app` will be redirected to standard input of `second-app`. This requires both applications to work on the same machine. All solutions below allow distributing producer and consumer across network.
- [socket](/questions/tagged/socket) - Java supports them natively and nicely
- [rmi](/questions/tagged/rmi) - de facto standard of Java-to-Java communication via binary protocol, [rpc](/questions/tagged/rpc)-like
- [web-services](/questions/tagged/web-services) - [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)-based protocol over [http](/questions/tagged/http), [soap](/questions/tagged/soap) or [rest](/questions/tagged/rest)
- [jms](/questions/tagged/jms) - asynchronously sending messages via *so-called* message broker
- shared database/file/memory, e.g. using [hazelcast](/questions/tagged/hazelcast)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html), so that persist your require data in the file and then other application read that data from file. this is simplest solution , in the more complex scenario you can use [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html)

Comment: This solution will work if you don't need to read the file as it is being written by the writer app.

Answer (score 0):

You can to it with socket (this is one of ways which two process can communicate with each other), you can find a sample here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're looking for IPC; inter process communication.

There are more options, but Java RMI(remote method invocation) could do it and it hides the low level socket implementation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html

Comment: well, give it a try; it's not very complicated

Answer (score 0):

if you have the source for the second program, you might just do redirection of the output of the first into your second: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29)